# How to derive an object type with another object's values in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create a function that will return a generic object type with keys that are derived from an argument passed into that function. A simplified example:

```js
// What do I put here for this to work?
type ObjectB<T> = {};

declare function makeObjectB<T>(a: T): ObjectB<T>;

const objectB = makeObjectB({
  name: "foo"
});

console.log(objectB.foo)
```

`typeof objectB` would result in something like:

```js
{
  foo: string
}
```

Bonus points if the following example could also be supported:

```js
// What do I put here for this to work?
type ObjectB<T> = {};

declare function makeObjectB<T>(a: T[]): ObjectB<T[]>;

const objectB = makeObjectB([{ name: "foo" }, { name: "bar" }]);

console.log(objectB.foo)
console.log(objectB.bar)

typeof objectB => { foo: string; bar: string }
```

Comment: Are you basically trying to define a type based on some kind of JSON-Schema-like schema?

Comment: Not quite, the actual types and functions I'm actually using this for is something completely different

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure it is, with a mapped type:

```
type ObjectB<T extends { name: string }> = {
    [K in T["name"]]: string;
};
```

You will notice the `extends { name: string }` after `T`. This is a generic constraint, which is *similar* to a function parameter type argument.

Inside the mapped type, we go through each `K` in `T["name"]` and map it to a `string`.

So if we had this: `ObjectB<{ name: "foo" }>`, `T["name"]` would be `"foo"` and this type would result in:

```
{
    foo: string;
}
```

With this type, we can write our function signature now:

```
declare function makeObjectB<T extends { name: string }>(a: T): ObjectB<T>;
```

You will also notice that the same generic constraint is present here. This is to satisfy TypeScript that `T` from `makeObjectB` can be used with `ObjectB`.

And for bonus points, we can define an overload:

```
declare function makeObjectB<T extends ReadonlyArray<{ name: string }>>(a: T): ObjectB<T[number]>;
```

`T` can now be any array of objects that have a `name` key that points to a string.

The other thing that's different here is using `ObjectB<T[number]>` instead of just `ObjectB<T>`. This lets us get all the elements in the array (technically tuple here) as a union, which means `T["name"]` is now something like `"foo" | "bar"`.

You can try this solution out [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA8gRgKwgY2AIQDwBUoQB7AQB2AJgM5QDeURAhgLYQBcUZwATgJZEDmUAvgD4oAXioBYAFBQZUANoBpKNyhY5AIjqN1AXR0s2XXgG4p-U5KkkUAG1rtoAMwCuRVJwD2RKPVoBrCHgkVEwcfEJSCgAlCFoSLxsQAEF2dloQDGotZlYObj4hQQAKWhYsAEoWIJR0bDkiZ3o4CHYdQQtrZDsHKBc3YE9vXwDqkOxcAmJyKhoGHMN8gWLS1UrYRBrQ9qkpSilZKGQvNigPDZDRH39A8-QivekD2WyWdUcPD3V92X4oWgojkQ2OULN8ZICyB4bBAAHQ2Dw8IpnYLoGHvDwgsw7SQPA4Q4CnW5oS7DG4otBFORZOavdHqAQAGhmLyg6jg9np-B0fwBx2AmMsj3BxyhsPhiORmzRHwFeJF0LhCKRRJh7PYAv4QA).